# VS Code Debug Console Not Showing line number for logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This seems to have just recently changed for me.  I like to log some messages and see the line/files it comes from, but now when I log an Object, the line number no longer shows.  Anyone have any ideas? Thanks
[image]

As you can see, the 'Test' log shows file name and line, but the obj log does not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"outputCapture": "console"` to a configuration in the launch.json helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't change my output by adding this
`  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node.js",
      "outputCapture": "console"
    }
  ]
}
`